# how to access value of parent class constant out side of class using child class

Tags: php

I have two classes
Class a as parent
Class b as child
Class a and class b both have same constant with some values
And i initialize child class b
Now if i want to access value of parent class constant out side of class using child class object $test
How can i do that.
For e.g `$test::version` //output 2.5.0, what i want 2.4.0

```
<?php
class a{
     const version='2.4.0';
    public function childClassVersion(){
        echo static::version;

    }
   public function parentClassVersion(){
        echo self::version;

    }
}
class b extends a{
         const version='2.5.0';
}
$test=new b;
echo $test::version; // output 2.5.0
echo "<br>";
echo b::version; // output 2.5.0
echo "<br>";
echo a::version; //output 2.4.0
echo "<br>";
$test->childClassVersion(); // output 2.5.0
echo "<br>";
$test->parentClassVersion(); // output 2.4.0
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what your issue is. You _can_ access both values as you show yourself, so what is missing?

Comment: using child class object access parent class constant

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `parent::version` ?

Comment: without class name or without any method ...just using child class object there is any techniques

Comment: As you already see - it's **not possible**.

Comment: parent::version outside of class ...which parent how can you know ??

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain from the discussion in the comments, but *maybe* this is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
class a{
    const version='2.4.0';
    public function childClassVersion(){
        return static::version;
    }
}
class b extends a{
    const version='2.5.0';
    public function parentClassVersion(){
        return parent::version;
    }
}
$test=new b;
var_dump($test::version); // output 2.5.0
var_dump(b::version); // output 2.5.0
var_dump(a::version); //output 2.4.0
var_dump($test->childClassVersion()); // output 2.5.0
var_dump($test->parentClassVersion()); // output 2.4.0
```

Comment: OP wants `$test::version` to output parent class constant (`2.4.0`).

Comment: Use $test object to get parent class  constant value ...It's not possible i think

Comment: @daulat Correct. Since you explicitly overwrite that constant in your child class there is no trace of the constant defined in the parent class. So the question is: _why_ do you need to access like that?

Comment: I just  want to know it is possible or not?